# Compile time enforced finite lists

Tags: list, haskell, dependent-type

I would like to make a type that represents lists with a finite number of elements.

Now the naïve way to do this is with strict evaluation:

```
data FiniteList a
  = Nil
  | Cons a !(List a)
```

With this infinite lists are equivalent to bottom.

However I want a type which prevents the creation of such lists altogether.  I would ideally like to have any attempts to build an infinite list cause a compile time error.

I can begin to see how this might be done if I build sized lists using `GADTs` and `DataKinds`.

```
data Natural = Zero | Succ Natural

data DependentList :: Natural -> Type -> Type where
  Nil  :: DependentList 'Zero a
  Cons :: a -> DependentList n a -> DependentList ('Succ n) a
```

If we try and build something like

```
a = Cons 1 a
```

We get a type error since this requires a type `n ~ 'Succ n`.

The issue with this is that it is not a single list type but rather a class of types, one for each size of list.  So for example if I wanted to write a version of `take` or `drop` on this list I would need to start getting into some serious dependent typing.

I would like to unify all of these separate types under a single type which still enforces finitude at compile time.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, just use an existential to forget the finite length afterwards:

```
data NonDependentList a where NonDependentList :: DependentList n a -> NonDependentList a
```

Of course, `take` and `drop` will have some boilerplate...

```
take :: Int -> NDL a -> NDL a
take n (NDL Nil) = NDL Nil
take n (NDL (Cons a as)) = case take (n-1) (NDL as) of
    NDL as' -> NDL (Cons a as')
```

But you still can't make an infinite one:

```
ones = NDL (Cons 1 (case ones of NDL os -> os)) -- existential escapes its scope
```

Comment: You can still try, getting bottom, by moving the pattern match out. Or, more simply, using `ones=ones`.

Comment: Interesting. If we could write `ones = case ones of ~(NonDependentList os) -> NonDependentList (Cons 1 os)` we would get an infinite list, and the only reason this is not working is because GADTs do not mix well with lazy patterns. Are we sure that we can't write some helper `nonBot :: NDL a->NDL a` such that `nonBot _|_ = NDL _|_` and `nonBot x=x` otherwise? This is doable with non-GADTs/existentials having a single constructor using e.g. lazy pattern matching: `nonBot ~(K x) = K x`

Comment: @dfeuer `undefined` inhabits all types, and so isn't worth mentioning as an exception to any type-system enforced property in my opinion. It is simply the background risk we accept in trade for being able to actually get things done in time.

Comment: Sure, but that's exactly the reason the OP rejects the simplest solution: a strict-spined list! Now it's true that the GADT approach can have performance advantages under certain circumstances, but that's not relevant to what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with Liquid Haskell, which provides termination checks.
Type signatures look like this in Liquid Haskell:

```
{-@ (function name) :: (refinement) [/ (termination metric)] @-}
```

The termination metric is an integer vector that is supposed to decrease each recursive call (lexicographical ordering). If not specified, LH will use the first integer argument as the termination metric.
Termination checking can be disabled with lazy annotation `{-@ lazy (function name) @-}`:

```
{-@ lazy inf @-}
inf x = x : inf x
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the ["ghosts of departed proofs"](https://kataskeue.com/gdp.pdf) approach, which involves a tagged newtype with carefully exposed smart constructors, and working in continuation-passing style with continuations polymorphic in the type tag:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, RankNTypes, RoleAnnotations #-} 
module FinList (FinList,empty,toFinList,cons) where 
-- FinList constructor should NOT be public, or else everything breaks!

newtype FinList name a = FinList { getFinList :: [a] } deriving Functor

-- Don't allow Data.Coerce.coerce to turn FinList X a into forall x. FinList x a
type role FinList nominal representational

empty :: forall a r. (forall name . FinList name a -> r) -> r
empty f = f (FinList [])

toFinList:: forall a r. Int -> [a] -> (forall name. FinList name a -> r) -> r
toFinList n as f = f (FinList (take n as))

cons :: forall a r name'. a -> FinList name' a -> (forall name. FinList name a -> r) -> r
cons a (FinList as) f = f (FinList (a:as))
```

This should prevent clients of the `FinList` module from creating circular definitions.

Comment: If you're going to carefully choose what operations to export, why bother with a type-level tag and fancy CPS stuff?

Comment: @DanielWagner I think that, without the polymorphic trick, code like  `bogus = FinList.cons 'a' bogus $ id` would be permitted.